# C++ socket, client can't send message to java server

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I am trying to get a two socket (one for sending and the other one for receiving) working.

Right now I can receive but I can't send. The server is written in java and I am trying to connect with a client written in c++.

This is the client part, I am opening a socket for sending in an if statement and if the expression is false I want to send a message, but it doesn't work.

```
if (function == "connect_to_server" ){
    status_s = getaddrinfo(&host_const[0], &port_const[0], &host_info_s, &host_info_list_s);

    if (status_s != 0)  std::cout << "getaddrinfo error" << gai_strerror(status_s) ;


    std::cout << "Creating a sending socket..."  << std::endl;
    socketfd_s = socket(host_info_list->ai_family, host_info_list->ai_socktype,
                      host_info_list->ai_protocol);
    if (socketfd_s == -1)  std::cout << "socket error " ;

    std::cout << "Host: " << &host_const[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Port: " << &port_const[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "function: " << function << std::endl;
    function.erase(std::remove(function.begin(), function.end(), '\n'), function.end());

    std::cout << "Connect()ing..."  << std::endl;
    status_s = connect(socketfd_s, host_info_list_s->ai_addr, host_info_list_s->ai_addrlen);
    if (status_s == -1)  std::cout << "connect error" ;
    cout << "socket : " << socketfd_s ;


    std::cout << "'Client connected....."  << std::endl;
   }
   else 
        std::cout << "send()ing total  message on anwser..."  << std::endl;
        char *msg_s = "some_string";
        int len_s;
        ssize_t bytes_sent_s;
        std::cout << msg_s;
        len_s = strlen(msg_s);
        std::cout << len_s << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Message not sent...."  << std::endl;
        bytes_sent_s = send(socketfd_s, msg_s, len_s, 0);
        //send(socketfd_s, msg_s, len_s, 0);
        std::cout << "Message sent....\n"  << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore();
        cout << "param1" << socketfd_s;
        cout << "param2" << len_s;
        cout << "param3" << msg_s;
        }
```

The connection to the server is established, but the string does not get send to the server.
Ah and the whole thing runs in a while (1){} to be able to receive more then one message.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, after starting the client nothing is sent, but if I kill it with ctrl - c the message is sent to the server.

thx in advance,

merl

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem in the client and not the server? What does the `send` call return? What does the exception actually say? What kind of socket? Oh, and that code is *not* C, it's C++, please edit your tags appropriately.

Comment: The exception says something like   end of line . I am pretty sure it's on client side, because with a different client it works.

Comment: What is the server expecting?  You are just sending 'some string', no newline or null terminator.

Comment: I just found out what the problem was, I was closing the socket after sending, but the server expects the socket to stay alive.

Comment: Honestly I'd like to see the Java code too. Might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have the java code, it is just a binary.

Comment: I'd really like to help you with this. Would you like to continue this outside of stackoverflow?
Edit: not sure if I'm even allowed to say that...

Comment: I would prefer to stay here, because if we solve it, the solution could maybe be helpful for someone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Ok fair enough. In that case, I'll have to go ahead and side with the rest of the people here in thinking that it's a problem with the binary. It likely closes the socket after reading the data, but it's hard to tell from our perspective.

Comment: I don't think so, because i tried different clients and it worked, it just does not work with mine. The thing is, if I start my client and kill it afterwards with ctrl - c the message is sent to the server.

Comment: What does the exception *say?* And ***don't*** tell us 'something like ...' It's of no interest and it doesnt answer the question.

Comment: The exception says java.net.SocketException: Host closed socket
Of course I am closing the socket if I kill the program, I already solved that problem.

Comment: No it doesn't, unless you throw that yourself, or otherwise lose what the actual text in the exception is, which is a complete waste of time. That text might say 'SocketException: socket closed', but until you report it accurately as already requestd, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that chars in Java are two bytes not 1 like in C. You should try std::wstring.

Another idea: use the length of the string PLUS 1 (in this case 2), to add the 0 (or two zero bytes) at the end of the string. Would be useful to know what is the server expecting.

Comment: thank you, but I figured out the problem was I was closing the socket after sending. But now my problem is it doesn't even send anymore....

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it with the help of someone from a different forum, the problem was I didn't send the line terminator.

And of course Martin James comment above also helped.

Comment: Did my comment 'What is the server expecting? You are just sending 'some string', no newline or null terminator.' - not help, then?

Comment: Yes it did, but I cant vote up your comment because I need a reputation of 15.